# Initialize variable error for java

Tags: java

First of; I am very new to programming...

What i am trying to do is have a simple program which calculates your grade based on your marks, here is what i have right now:

```
 class Grade {

public static void main(String[]args){


char grade;


    int marks = 92;

    if(marks<60) 
    grade = 'F' ;

    else if(marks>61 && marks<69)
    grade = 'D';

    else if(marks>70 && marks<79)
    grade = 'C';

    else if(marks>80 && marks<89)
    grade = 'B';

    else if(marks>90 && marks<99)
    grade = 'A';

    else
    System.out.println("Bogus Grade");


    System.out.println("Your grade is " + grade);


}


}
```

(For now i'm just specifying the grade in the code, and will work on user input later)

While trying to compile the code I get this error:

```
  Grade.Java:30: error: variable grade might not have been initialized
                  System.out.println("Your grade is" + grade);
                                                       ^
```

Comment: Have you googled this?

Comment: Set the `marks` to `60` and you will see the problem. The `grade` variable needs to be set like `char grade = 'I';` or something similar. Then fix your if/else blocks to handle the grades (e.g. `<=` instead of `<`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's possible to get through all the cases and have grade not be set.

Set a value to grade at the start:

```
char grade = 'Z';
```

Also make sure all cases are taken care of, and grade set all the time. In the final else, `grade` is not modified. You can do:

```
else {
    System.out.println("Bogus Grade");
    grade = 'Z';
}
```

**Also**, values of marks equal to 60, 70, 80, 90 and 100 are never taken into account. You should change the if lines to:

```
else if(marks>=60 && marks<69)
...
else if(marks>=70 && marks<79)
...
else if(marks>=80 && marks<89)
...
else if(marks>=90 && marks<=100)
...
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: They also need to fix 70, 80, 90, and 100.

Comment: @gpojd Yes, just noticed. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where `grade` isn't initialized.  What if `grade` is `101`?  What if it's `-1`?  In that case, the `else` block doesn't initialize `grade`, and Java won't allow a possible case where a local variable is not initialized before it is used.

You must explicitly initialize it, so initialize it to something when you declare it.

```
char grade = 'Z';
```

At the end, only print the grade if it was changed from `'Z'`:

```
if (grade != 'Z') {
   System.out.println("Your grade is " + grade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `char grade = '0';` at the start.

Also use brackets since you are using a lot of if-statements. They can get pretty confusing after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are not initialised by default so you have to give them an initial value.

```
char grade = 'Z';
```

This only applies if you reach a point in your code where the variable could not have a value.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html